# How to reference color in XAML

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI project I have the standard Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml and I want to reference colors in there from my other XAML files like this:

```
<StackLayout
 BackgroundColor="{Color MyCustomColor}"
 Orientation="Horizontal"
 VerticalOptions="Start">
```

Comment: Use {StaticResource MyCustomColor}

Comment: `StaticResource` can not be found

Comment: Works for me `<Rectangle WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Fill="{StaticResource Primary}" />`

Comment: It works for me too now, after restarting Visual Studio

Comment: Glad you solved it. Here is the doc for [Resource Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries) which you may refer to.